# SAS dynamic arrays with changing start and stop values

Tags: arrays, dynamic, sas, longitudinal

I am working on a longitudinal dataset where each row is a subject and each column is an event.  There are no limits to the number of events that a subject can have, but the events are coded in a few ways.  For the sake of this example let's say one of the coded ways is binary (good, bad).

I am trying to find 
1) all of the event strings consisting of 3 or more events (with no count limit) that are within 24 hours of one another (on the same subject) from start to finish.  There also may be multiple successes of this criteria within the same subject.

2) for each of the successes (string of 3 or more events within 24 hours) I need to count the number of good events.

I've included code that generates similar data to mine.  For now I'm simplifying to 26 observations but I have up to 42 for a single subject.

```
  data examp;
informat subject 4. epdt1   epdt2   epdt3   epdt4   epdt5   epdt6   epdt7   epdt8   epdt9   epdt10  epdt11  epdt12  epdt13  epdt14  epdt15  epdt16  epdt17  epdt18  epdt19  epdt20  epdt21  epdt22  epdt23  epdt24  epdt25  epdt26 datetime20.
    good1   good2   good3   good4   good5   good6   good7   good8   good9   good10  good11  good12  good13  good14  good15  good16  good17  good18  good19  good20  good21  good22  good23  good24  good25  good26 1.;
input subject   epdt1   epdt2   epdt3   epdt4   epdt5   epdt6   epdt7   epdt8   epdt9   epdt10  epdt11  epdt12  epdt13  epdt14  epdt15  epdt16  epdt17  epdt18  epdt19  epdt20  epdt21  epdt22  epdt23  epdt24  epdt25  epdt26
            good1   good2   good3   good4   good5   good6   good7   good8   good9   good10  good11  good12  good13  good14  good15  good16  good17  good18  good19  good20  good21  good22  good23  good24  good25  good26;
format subject: 4. epdt: datetime20. good: 1.;
datalines;
3098    .   .   25JUL1998:01:46:27  25JUL1998:02:16:05  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
3021    13JAN1999:17:31:37  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
1982    01FEB1998:02:29:01  12APR1999:19:49:00  03JUN2018:21:00:00  13AUG1999:13:39:00  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   1   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
1093    11APR2015:16:10:57  30AUG2015:00:52:28  14SEP2015:08:24:25  09MAY1999:00:28:37  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
4089    29JUN1998:05:18:34  23JUL1998:18:31:11  07FEB1999:05:25:45  07FEB1999:05:29:26  07FEB1999:05:32:04  07FEB1999:05:34:05  14FEB1999:18:00:13  14FEB1999:18:01:02  14FEB1999:18:03:24  14FEB1999:18:05:55  14FEB1999:18:16:45  14FEB1999:18:19:04  14FEB1999:18:31:57  14FEB1999:18:35:22  28JUL1998:18:32:02  31DEC1998:00:22:33  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   .   1   .   1   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
3055    18FEB1998:11:34:00  14JUL1998:01:20:34  13OCT1998:10:49:08  30OCT1998:18:14:58  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
1239    07MAR1998:06:02:18  01JUN1998:08:18:20  23JUN1998:07:52:11  04JUL1998:08:47:04  29JUL1998:23:16:41  29JUL1998:23:30:03  29JUL1998:23:42:56  30JUL1998:00:08:03  30JUL1998:00:12:30  30JUL1998:00:14:58  30JUL1998:00:36:00  30JUL1998:00:38:33  30JUL1998:00:57:56  30JUL1998:01:01:03  30JUL1998:01:06:10  30JUL1998:01:16:50  30JUL1998:01:24:19  30JUL1998:01:32:30  30JUL1998:01:42:55  30JUL1998:01:50:24  30JUL1998:02:08:46  30JUL1998:02:20:18  30JUL1998:02:22:08  30JUL1998:02:28:52  30JUL1998:02:31:29  30JUL1998:02:51:29  .   .   1   .   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   .   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   .   1
9834    10JUL1999:20:22:24  14JUL1999:00:52:02  14JUL1999:17:02:38  14JUL1999:17:30:06  21FEB2000:12:41:34  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
run;
proc sort data=examp; by subject;


data epwide_dt1;
format  apppair $7000.;
set examp;

by subject;
%macro loops;
array eptm (*)epdt1-epdt26;    array apptm (*)  good1-good26;
*********using the starting value for identifying pairs;
*******trimmed then for the sake of making the macro work;
%do start=1 %to 26;
    %do stop=3 %to 26;  
%if &start.<&stop. %then %do ;
/***********to figure out if the difference between the pairs of times are 24 hours;*/
tbtw=eptm[&stop.]-eptm[&start.];
/*  *********number of points between them;*/
diff=(&stop.)- (&start.);
*******calculate the summaries between all episodes from start to stop;
array appr&start.&stop. (*) ap&start.-ap&stop.;
array stmct&start.&stop.(*) st&start.-st&stop.;
    %do i=&start. %to &stop.;
******calculate the number of appropriate episodes;
    if apptm[&i] ne . then appr&start.&stop.[&i]=apptm[&i];
    else appr&start.&stop.[&i]=0;
totapp=sum(of appr&start.&stop.(*));
if totapp=. then totapp=0;

****after you calculate the total value dump the array before the next itteration;
/*call missing(of appr&start.&stop.{*});*/

if (eptm[&start.] ne . and eptm[&stop.] ne . and diff>=2 and .<tbtw<86400 and totapp>1 ) then do;
appPair=catx(" ",apppair,"(",strip(put(&start., 3.)),"-",strip(put(&stop.,3.)),":", strip(put(totapp,3.)),"Good)");
end;


%end;
%end;
%end;
%end;
%mend;
%loops ;
run;
```

The error message below is what's resulting:

```
ERROR: Array subscript out of range at line 1 column 2.
apppair=  subject=1093 epdt1=11APR2015:16:10:57 epdt2=30AUG2015:00:52:28 epdt3=14SEP2015:08:24:25
epdt4=09MAY1999:00:28:37 epdt5=. epdt6=. epdt7=. epdt8=. epdt9=. epdt10=. epdt11=. epdt12=. epdt13=. epdt14=. epdt15=.
epdt16=. epdt17=. epdt18=. epdt19=. epdt20=. epdt21=. epdt22=. epdt23=. epdt24=. epdt25=. epdt26=. good1=. good2=.
good3=. good4=. good5=. good6=. good7=. good8=. good9=. good10=. good11=. good12=. good13=. good14=. good15=. good16=.
good17=. good18=. good19=. good20=. good21=. good22=. good23=. good24=. good25=. good26=. FIRST.subject=1
LAST.subject=1 tbtw=1323117 diff=1 ap1=0 ap2=0 ap3=0 st1=. st2=. st3=. totapp=0 ap4=0 st4=. ap5=0 st5=. ap6=0 st6=.
ap7=0 st7=. ap8=0 st8=. ap9=0 st9=. ap10=0 st10=. ap11=0 st11=. ap12=0 st12=. ap13=0 st13=. ap14=0 st14=. ap15=0
st15=. ap16=0 st16=. ap17=0 st17=. ap18=0 st18=. ap19=0 st19=. ap20=0 st20=. ap21=0 st21=. ap22=0 st22=. ap23=0 st23=.
ap24=0 st24=. ap25=0 st25=. ap26=0 st26=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=1
NOTE: Missing values were generated as a result of performing an operation on missing values.
      Each place is given by: (Number of times) at (Line):(Column).
      1 at 35:20     1 at 57:20     1 at 83:20     1 at 113:20    1 at 147:20    1 at 185:20    1 at 227:20
      1 at 273:20    1 at 323:20    1 at 377:20    1 at 435:20    1 at 497:20    1 at 563:20    1 at 633:20
      1 at 707:20    1 at 785:20    1 at 867:20    1 at 953:20    1 at 1043:20   1 at 1137:20   1 at 1235:20
      1 at 1337:20
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: There were 2 observations read from the data set WORK.EXAMP.
WARNING: The data set WORK.EPWIDE_DT1 may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0 observations and
         109 variables.
WARNING: Data set WORK.EPWIDE_DT1 was not replaced because this step was stopped.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           2.35 seconds
      cpu time            2.13 seconds
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Thank you for providing code and a description. Try using `options mprint;` before you run your code so that the log shows more information about what the macro code resolves to. Then please also update your question with an extract from the log showing the error message and surrounding code.

Comment: Please post your data as text, ideally using datalines in a data step so that it is imported in the correct format to run your code, and work on converting your code to a [minimal, verifiable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 

Also, see if you can get it to work without using macro code first, before adding that extra layer of complexity.

Comment: Why are you using macro for this? Does the structure of the data files change in some way?

Comment: @user667489 Thank you for the suggestion regarding the datalines.  I've added here and I agree getting it to work without the macro would be great but the reason that I'm introducing the macros is so that it will loop through all possible "pairs" and I'm using &start and &stop to iterate through those.  Still worth thinking about on my end.

Comment: @Tom as I mentioned above it was the only way that I could think of to loop through all possible points but then still use the stop and start values to add across the good variable to count the number of good events.  I could get it to loop to find the time but then I couldn't find a function in the array that would sum across variables from start to stop that wasn't (sum of *) and for this you need a defined array, which is only a subset of the original array AND it changes with each pair of observations you look at.

Comment: @Amir I will add that.  I will update the post so you can see that.

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of the 24 hour window?  Do you mean the current time is within 24 hours of the previous time?  Or within 24 hours of the first time in the "run"? If the later then do you want to find multiple overlapping runs? Say you recorded every 6 hours for 6 events.  Is that one run of 6*6 hours? Or a series of partially overlapping 24 hour windows?

Comment: Sure, in the way that I'm using it 24 hour window means that the difference in the time of the starting event and the ending event is less than 24 hours.  Right now I'm looking at overlapping runs because there are more conditions beyond good being evaluated and I want to get the "best" run which include other parameters.  In the end only non overlapping runs will be used, but for the sake of evaluation I think we need to consider them all. Great question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I quite understand your full problem.  But consider that if you want to sum the subset of values in an array from index START to index STOP you just use a DO loop.

For example to sum X10 to X20 you could use code like this:

```
array x (100) ;
start=10;
stop=20;
do i=start to stop;
   total=sum(total,0,x(i));
end;
```

So you should be able to solve this without macro code. Which should make debugging much easier.

Comment: So this is a great way to get the sum across those values and I wouldn't have thought of that.  My issues is that the start and stop values need to consider all of the possible combination of events that are within 24 hours of one another.

Comment: In the example above subject 4089, I need it to count start 3 stop 6 (because they are in 24 hours of one another) AND on that same subject I need it to count between 7 and 15 because they are also within 24 hours of one another.

Comment: your solution for the total array worked!!!  I was able to remove the subset of the array and it's working.  I'll post the solution below!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working!!!  I used @Tom 's suggestion to remove the need for creating a sub array of each of the pairs, as it was causing ALOT of problems.  I also streamlined the output and asked it to output each pair that is "Good" so that I will be able to evaluate them easier.  Previously it was creating appPair (my evaluation summary for each iteration within the start stop loop producing a bunch of extraneous output).

```
data epwide_dt1;
set examp;

by subject;
if first.subject then totapp=0;
%macro loops;
array eptm (*)epdt1-epdt26;
array apptm (*)  good1-good26;
*********using the starting value for identifying pairs;
%do start=1 %to 24;
    %do stop=3 %to 26;  
%if &start.<&stop. %then %do ;
totapp=0;
/***********to figure out if the difference between the pairs of times are 24 hours;*/
tbtw=eptm[&stop.]-eptm[&start.];
/*  *********number of points between them;*/
diff=(&stop.)- (&start.);

    %do i=&start. %to &stop.;
******calculate the number of good events;
totapp=sum(totapp, 0,apptm[&i]);

***output the summary on the pair that can be evaluated in the next step;
if &i=&stop. and (eptm[&start.] ne . and eptm[&stop.] ne . and diff>=2 and 0<tbtw<86400 and totapp>1 ) then do;
appPair=catx(" ","(",strip(put(&start., 3.)),"-",strip(put(&stop.,3.)),":", strip(put(totapp,3.)),"Good)");
   output;
    end;


%end;
%end;
%end;
%end;
%mend;
%loops ;
run;
```

Comment: I still do not understand why you are using macro code.